# What's i in each_with_index block

Tags: ruby, block

Okay, so im reading a guide for ruby and I can't make sense of this code. Where did i come from. I see that n is passed to iterate through the block but I have no idea where I comes from. If I could get a full explanation and breakdown of how this code works that would be great!

```
class Array
  def iterate!
    self.each_with_index do |n, i|
      self[i] = yield(n)
    end
  end
end

array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

array.iterate! do |n|
  n ** 2
end
```

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index

Comment: So do you understand the `yield` but not the `i` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some methods that are called with code blocks will pass more than one value to the block, so you end up with multiple block arguments (in your case the block arguments are n and i, which will hold the current item in the array (n) and the index of it (i)).

You can find out how many arguments a block will be passed by looking at the documentation for a method ([here's the docs for each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)). It does look like the extra values come from nowhere at first, and it takes a little while to memorize what a block will be passed when different methods are called.

Answer (score 3):

`i` is the index of the element (hence the name, `each_with_index`).

Answer (score 0):

`i` is commonly used as what's known as an "iterative variable". Basically, the loop block that you've copied here goes through each "iteration" of the loop and uses a new value of `i` and assigns it to the variable `n`, which is then passed on to the operation at the second to last line. In this case, the new value is simply the next number in `array`, and so there are four iterations of the loop.